# What does .. in ms sql server mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In some queries I noticed that selection of a table looks like

```
select *
from ..TableName
```

And this table has `dbo` scheme.

So, is this the same thing as

```
select *
from dbo.TableName
```

and I can use `..` just for comfort?
What does `..` mean? Is it only acronym for `dbo` or I can use it somewhere else?

Comment: instead of `databasename.schemaname.tablename`, .. is used

Comment: thanks a lot, sorry for duplicate, I couldn't find similar question

Comment: I've seen the schema omitted quite frequently when referencing another database. e.g. `master..spt_values` - I didn't realise that you could do `..` and even `...` until now but there doesn't seem any point as just omitting the dots would have the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- first `.` is for current database name
- second `.` is for default schema (`dbo`)

In [**Sql server**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx), complete name of an object is made up of four identifiers:

> server_name.[database_name].[schema_name].object_name